# How to use SUMPRODUCT with a conditional involving two cell ranges to calculate a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m working on an Excel spreadsheet, and I need to calculate a value using the SUMPRODUCT function. Here’s the scenario:

1. I have three sales locations: store1, store2, and store3.
2. For each location, I have the following data:
   Sales: Represented in column C.
   Margin: Represented in column D.

The calculation I want to perform is as follows:

- For each location, multiply the sales by the corresponding margin and sum up these products.
- Then, divide this sum by the total sales across all locations.

How can I achieve this using the SUMPRODUCT function? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you actually have "sales" and "margin" in your column B? It looks like instead you're using Spanish in there.  Change one to English or the other to Spanish and see.  Also, what kind of error is it giving you? `#NAME` or `#VAL` or `#NA` or ...?

Comment: Yes I have "sales" and "margin" in same column. Sorry for the laguage, I have Excel in portuguese and I failed in some translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `SUMPRODUCT` is used to select cells within a range with text, the result for each evaluation will either be TRUE or FALSE. You will need to convert this to 1's or 0's by using '--' before the function so that when you multiply it by another range of cells, you will get the expected value

*SUMPRODUCT Example:* Sum of column B where column A is equal to 'Sales"

```
       A      B
1 |  Sales    5
2 |  Sales    6
3 |  Margin   3
4 |  Margin   2
```

Resulting Formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4 = "Sales"),B1:B4)`

**How `SUMPRODUCT` works:**

First, an array is returned that has True for each value in A1:A4 that equals "Sales", and False for each value that doesn't

```
Sales           TRUE
Sales      ->   TRUE
Margin          FALSE
Margin          FALSE
```

Then the double negative converts TRUE to 1 and False to 0

```
1
1
0
0
```

Next, the first array (now the one with 1's and 0's) is multiplied by your second array (B1:B4) to get a new array

```
1st    2nd      New Array
1   *   5   =      5
1   *   6   =      6
0   *   3   =      0
0   *   2   =      0
```

Finally all the values in the new array are summed to get your result (5+6+0+0 = 11)
**Step 1:**

For your scenario, you're going to need find the sales amount for each Location and multiply it by the margin for the corresponding location

location 1: sales * margin

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A11="loja1"),--(B3:B11="venda"),(C3:C11)) * SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A11="loja1"),--(B3:B11="margem"),(C3:C11))`

You can do a similar formula for location 2 and 3 and then sum them all together.

**Step: 2**

To sum the sales for all locations, you can do a similar formula, again using the double negative, i.e. "--"

`SUMPRODUCT(--(B3:B11="sales"),(C3:C11))`

The resulting formula will be a bit long, but when you divide Step 1 by Step 2, you'll get the desired result

Comment: Tks man, but and the margin? In the step1 you used a location and sales and in step2 you used a sales.

Comment: apologies for confusion, forgot to include that part. It would be similar to how location 1's sales is found, I've updated the answer to reflect it

Comment: I tried something more simple, without location and nothing!
=SUMPRODUCT(-(B3:B11="sales"),-(B3:B11="margin"),(D3:D11))

Comment: you get nothing because there's no cell in B3:B11 that equals 'sales' and 'margin' obviously. I'll update my answer to show how `SUMPRODUCT` works and then if that doesn't help, maybe you can search around SO for other examples of `SUMPRODUCT`